# copying files from many directories to one using rsync

Tags: rsync

Is it possible to copy files from various subdirectories to one single directory. For example I have a structure that looks like:

```
+ dir1
  + file1.ext
  + file2.ext
+ dir2
  + file3.ext
  + file4.ext
  + subdir
     +dontwanttocopy.ext
```

Currently I am using the following command

```
find "//mysourcepathdirectory/" -maxdepth 2 -type f -name "*.ext" -exec rsync -vr -e ssh {} user@server:/mypath/videos/ \;
```

This command of course cause me to log repeatedly to the server. I would like a command that require me to login only one time. I am using an SSH key to avoid the pain but something is telling me that this is not the right approach. I would like to use rsync because only a few files will change over time. Also I would like to avoid copying files in subdirectories below my main path (e.g., subdir in the example above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is `rsync` command with `-r` (recursive copy) option.

```
rsync -r /path/in/source/dir*/*.ext /path/to/destination
```

You could even use `--exclude` option to exclude sub-directories and directories structures.

```
rsync -rv --exclude='*/' /path/in/source/dir*/ /path/to/destination/
```

Or with sub-directories:

```
rsync -rv --exclude='*/*' /path/in/source/dir*/ /path/to/destination/
```

You could also use `scp` command as well

```
scp -r /path/in/source/dir*/*.ext /path/to/destination
```

Comment: Thanks; I dont want to copy the directory structure; in my example above I would like `file1.ext`, `file2.ext`, `file3.ext`, and `file4.ext` to be in the same destination directory if that make sense. I though `rsync -r` will copy the source directory structure.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I used your command and worked but not sure the `--include` switch is doing anything here since there is no parameter (value) associated with it. Not sure if I am missing something. However in the other hand I was able to use the `--exclude` option since all my subdirs that I want to avoid have the same pattern. My command now looks like:

`rsync -vr --exclude misc/ -e ssh //mysourcepath/*/*.mp4 user@server:/destpath/myvidtest/`